# Starting Python and PyQt - Tutorials, Books, general approaches

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

After doing web development (php/js) for the last few years i thought it is about time to also have a look at something different. I thought it may be always good to have look of different areas in programming to understand some different approaches better, so i now want to have look at GUI development.

As programming language i did choose Python where i now slowly get the basics and i also found this question:

[How to learn python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988/how-to-learn-python)

which already contains good links and book proposals. So i am now mainly looking for some infos about PyQt:

- Tutorials
- Books
- General tips for GUI development

I already looked at some tutorials, but didn't find any really good ones. Most were pretty short and didn't really explain anything.

Thanks in advance for advises.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that you'll get more mileage out of understanding Qt than understanding PyQt.  Most of the good documentation discusses Qt, not PyQt, so getting conversant with them (and how to convert that code to PyQt code) is a lifesaver.  Note, I don't actually recommend *programming* Qt in C++; Python is a fantastic language for Qt programming, since it takes care of a lot of gruntwork, leaving you to actually code application logic.

The best book I've found for working with PyQt is [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html).  It's got a nice small Python tutorial in the front, then takes you through the basics of building a Qt application.  By the end of the book you should have a good idea of how to build an application, and some basic idea of where to start for more advanced topics.

The other critical reference is the [bindings documentation for PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html).  Pay particular attention to the "New-style Signal and Slot Support"; it's a *huge* improvement over the old style.  Once you really understand that document (and it's pretty short) you'll be able to navigate the Qt docs pretty easily.

Comment: Too bad this is for PyQt4 and I can't seem to find a good book on PyQt5 :-/

Answer (score 4):

I had this bookmark saved:

http://www.harshj.com/2009/04/26/the-pyqt-intro/

Answer (score 4):

There is a [step-by-step guide](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/setting-up-ide-and-creating-a-cross-platform-qt-python-gui-application/) at popdevelop.com on how to set up Eclipse with PyQT.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be: have some particular goal in mind, some app that you, or even better someone else, would use in a real world scenario.

I started with the same book Chris B mentioned, i.e. [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html) and I found it useful and it touched many of the topics you would need in most GUI applications. Additionally, after some time and some confidence gained, you want to have [PyQT Classes](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/classes.html) handy.

Do not avoid C++ examples to explain some problem you'd like to solve, rewriting it in Python is not that hard (depending on the problem, and scope of course).