# Learning PyQt Quickly

Tags: python, pyqt

For a college project, I need to implement a GUI for a console app I wrote. For this I decided to use PyQt. I need only basic functionalities, such as designing a simple form with basic elements and displaying some texts on it.

Can anyone point me to a nice tutorial for learning PyQt? I really don't want to get into the details of Qt at this stage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting Python and PyQt - Tutorials, Books, general approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113002/starting-python-and-pyqt-tutorials-books-general-approaches)

Comment: If you're on Linux, try PyGTK it's much better!

Answer (score 6):

The best way to learn PyQt is the book "[Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html)" from Mark Summerfield. That's the way I learned PyQt.
Another very good source is the homepage of [PySide](http://www.pyside.org). They also provide a Python Qt wrapper which is compatible to PyQt. It has a very nice documentation (with real python examples, not C++ like PyQt).

Answer (score 6):

You can read [PyQT by Example](https://ralsina.me/stories/BBS47.html), a series of blog posts by [Roberto Alsina](https://ralsina.me/).

Comment: Both links are down.

Answer (score 5):

There is a really great Tutorial I used to learn pyqt: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/

This PyQt tutorial is also available in German language

Comment: Found this to be the most concise,quick and explanative set of tutorials in comparision to other answers

Answer (score 0):

you need to see the orginal pyqt Examples
you need time for practice
you get Experience

you must specify a goal and start Researching about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Learn PyQT by Video Tutorials.
You can follow the http://webtech-training.blogspot.in/2014/05/learn-pyqt-step-by-step.html