# New-style Signal and Slot Support, PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, pyuic

I'm writing a GUI application with PyQt4 (Python3). One my friend pointed out that using pyuic4 is a bad practice and referred me to uic module and Connecting Slots By Name features. He didn't have time to explain more and the references I have are rather short, I couldn't grasp the idea from them ([uic module](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html#the-uic-module), [LoadingUIFilesAtRuntime](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/LoadingUIFilesAtRuntime), [connecting slots by name](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name)).

On StackOverflow there is at least one [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113002/starting-python-and-pyqt-tutorials-books-general-approaches) but the links to the literature are broken there.

I could follow standard tutorials and did simple GUI using pyuic, but now feel a little bit confused... Any good examples and/or references are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, using `pyuic4` is certainly not "bad practice".

There are three main ways to get PyQt4 UI's into your code:

- Write it all by hand yourself
- Use `pyuic4` to auto-generate a python module that can be imported
- Use the `uic` package to load `ui` files directly at runtime

Of these, the first two are by far the most common, and most documentation, tutorials, advice, etc that you will come across will use those methods.

A good source for PyQt4 tutorials can be found in [this section](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials) of the [PyQt4 Wiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/StartPage). However, I should probably point out that, although still relevant, many of them are quite old and so still use the old-style signals and slots.

However, the difference between the old- and new- styles is not that difficult to understand, so maybe a simple example is all that's needed.

Here's the old-style way to connect a button-click signal to a handler method (aka slot):

```
self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.handleButtonClick)
```

and here's the new-style way:

```
self.button.clicked(self.handleButtonClick)
```

As you can see, the new-style is much simpler and more pythonic. On the other hand, the old-style is quite similar to how signals are connected using C++ (and for this reason can still be useful in certain circumstances).

If you have problems with connecting signals when writing your GUIs, you can always ask a question here - but it's much easier to get good answers if you ask specific questions that include example code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references. New style looks really easier. And I should probably ask once more my friend what he means by saying: combining two approaches, LoadUI and connect by name, makes a lot of sense.